# Unable to retrieve lastName and firstName from firestore document in VueJs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I am trying to display last Name and first Name from a document stored upon signup with a field displayName. I thought that having a displayName as a common key would allow me to retrieve last name and first name of the user signing up by making a request to firestore using the displayName property stored in the currentUser object that is returned once I have logged in. However, I cannot access the lastName from the firebase documents and would really appreciate help.

```
<template>
  <p>Process Payroll</p>
  <h1>{{ user.displayName }} </h1>
  <h1>{{ docs }} </h1>
</template>

<script>
import getUser from '@/composables/getUser'
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore, projectAuth } from '@/firebase/config'
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router'

export default {
    setup() {
    const { user } = getUser();

    watch(()=> user, () => returnUser())

    const lastName = ref("");
    const firstName = ref("");
    const docs = ref([]);

    const returnUser = async () => {
      const res = await projectFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .where("displayName", "==", "Abe")
        .get();
      if (!error.value) {
        // check your response here.
        console.log(res);
        const doc = res.filter((userObj) => {
          if ("Abe" === userObj.data().displayName) {
            return userObj.data().lastName;
          }
        });
        docs.value = doc;
      }
    };

    onMounted(returnUser)

    return { user, docs, returnUser};
  },
}
</script>
```

There's only a blank array being returned in place of the lastName. I also don't see any requests made by firebase to retrieve the information needed. I get a reference error:error is undefined in my console as well as cannot read property displayName of null despite using a watch to make sure that the user object is uploaded after. Can someone please help with major code changes to help me get through my errors and display the lastname from firebase. Please help! I am new to Vuejs.

[image]

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectAuth } from '../firebase/config'

// refs
const user = ref(projectAuth.currentUser)

// auth changes
projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged(_user => {
  console.log('User state change. Current user is:', _user)
  user.value = _user
});

const getUser = () => {
  return { user } 
}

export default getUser
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You only have a single request here which fetches docs with `displayName` exactly equal to `Abe`. Is the last name stored in same field? Can you share a screenshot of your document? Also that `if ("Abe" === userObj.data().displayName)` is redundant since your query includes  `.where("displayName", "==", "Abe")`.

Comment: The 'Abe' string was originally user.displayName where user is a object that is defined when the user logs in. I have added a screenshot of the document as you requested

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log all firstName + lastName combinations then try this:

```
const returnUser = async () => {
  const res = await projectFirestore
    .collection("users")
    .where("displayName", "==", "Abe") // Case sensitive
    .get();

  const lastNameList = res.docs.map(d => `Abe ${d.data().lastName}`)
  console.log(lastNameList)
  docs.value = lastNameList;
}
```

Try changing the getUser function like this so displayName is always defined.

```
const getUser = () => {
  // set default value to null
  return user ? { user } : { displayName: "NoUser" } 
}
```

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the errors that I am seeing in my console. I do not want to log all firstName+lastName combinations. Only the firstName lastName that matches the user.displayName where user is the currently logged in user. I need help with getting rid of the errors that I am seeing and displaying the user.displayName for which I am setting ```watch(()=> user, () => returnUser()) ``` but I am still not able to use the user.displayName property.

Comment: I am getting an error cannot read property parent node of null. Do you know why that might be? @Dharmaraj

Comment: @BilalHussain what is default value of user from `getUser`? That does not have this property. Try changing to `<h1>{{ user.displayName ? user.displayName : "No name" }} </h1>`

Comment: I shared the getUser composable which returns the user, once the user is logged in (as seen in the console). I am requesting your assistance in helping me retrieve the user.displayName in the script part of the component. In template where you mentioned to change the h1, I am correctly able to see user.displayName. I attached the User composable for your reference. I might be calling returnUser before the projectAuth callback updates the user which is why I can't use it in the script but it's available in the template.

Comment: @BilalHussain I would set default value of user to null and then let `onAuthStateChanged` update the user state. check my updated answer which will return an object with default displayname or something.

Comment: I'm trying to say that user.displayName is not defined when I use it as a query in place of the name "Abe". I originally want to query from firebase using the user.displayName value.

Comment: @BilalHussain the displayName is coming from Firebase Auth User Object. Are you sure you have set that user's displayName since it's undefined by default ?

Comment: @BilalHussain can you then `console.log(user)` right before Firestore query and check if it logs correctly ?

Comment: I attached another screenshot showing that displayName in the user object is instantiated . I am able to access this displayName in the template on top ```<h1>{{ user.displayName }} </h1> ``` but I am unable to use this inside the <script> </script tag where I need to use it to query the database instead of using 'Abe' (which was for test purposes).

Comment: I added a screenshot showing the place where I want to use user.displayName. Even though I console.log(user) and it shows up with the user object, when I console.log(user.displayName) it returns an undefined. Does it make sense?

Comment: @BilalHussain is this on Github by chance so it's easier to replicate the issue ??

Comment: It took me a while but here's the repository for you https://github.com/Bilolhussain/VueJsFirebase @Dharmaraj